# Doing multiple calculations in R similar to Data table in excel

Tags: r, excel

I am looking for a similar function/package in R to that of Data Table in MS Excel (What-If calculations). Currently I use Data tables in Excel extensively to do multiple calculations on thousands of rows of input data. I have attached a snapshot of the calculations being done in Excel Data Table:

[image]

In other words, all my formulae/calculations are in a single tab of spreadsheet, and all the input data in another tab (several thousand of rows). I use data table operation to calculate results for each row of this data set. This makes my spreadsheet tidy with all the calculations in only single tab. Now I am looking to implement the same using R. Any help on this is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @zx8754 I have now added an image of the calculations from Excel Data table to make my question clearer. Tried my best to put across my query.

Comment: Assuming your input dataframe is named *df1*, we can calculate *Calc1* as: `df1$Calc1 <- df1$X * df1$Y`, for *Calc2*: `df1$Calc2 <- df1$Z / df1$Y`, and for *Calc3*: `df1$Calc3 <- df1$Z + df1$X`.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's make your problem reproducible:

```
df <- data.frame(case = 1:12,
                 x = seq(10, 120, by = 10),
                 y = seq(0.5, 1.6, by = 0.1),
                 z = seq(100, 210, by = 10))
head(df)
#   case  x   y   z
# 1    1 10 0.5 100
# 2    2 20 0.6 110
# 3    3 30 0.7 120
# 4    4 40 0.8 130
# 5    5 50 0.9 140
# 6    6 60 1.0 150
```

Then, we can solve this the traditional way:

```
df$calc1 <- df$x * df$y
df$calc2 <- df$z / df$y
df$calc3 <- df$z + df$x

head(df)
#   case  x   y   z calc1    calc2 calc3
# 1    1 10 0.5 100     5 200.0000   110
# 2    2 20 0.6 110    12 183.3333   130
# 3    3 30 0.7 120    21 171.4286   150
# 4    4 40 0.8 130    32 162.5000   170
# 5    5 50 0.9 140    45 155.5556   190
# 6    6 60 1.0 150    60 150.0000   210
```

Alternatively, you could use `transform`:

```
transform(df, calc1 = x / y, calc2 = z / y, calc3 = z + x)
```